# Error when run cucumber with dry run option

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm trying to improve the speed of running tests by opening and closing the browser only once.

http://watirmelon.com/2012/04/01/five-page-object-anti-patterns/

I have the following in hooks.rb

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new ENV['BROWSER'].to_sym

Before do
  @browser = browser
end

After do |scenario|
  @browser.cookies.clear
end

at_exit do
  browser.close
end
```

It greatly boosts up the speed of test suite running. But I also need some statistics in json file from my custom formatter without running tests:

```
cucumber -t @test -d -f Cucumber::Formatter::MyCustomFormatter > result.json
```

The problem is that cucumber catches error with `-d` option:

```
uninitialized constant Watir (NameError)
/home/user/work/repository/features/support/hooks.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load_code_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Then I try to move `Watir.new` method inside `Before` block:

```
Before do
  if !$somevar
    browser = Watir::Browser.new ENV['BROWSER'].to_sym
    @browser = browser
    $somevar = true
  end
end
```

And get error in `at_exit` block:

```
/home/user/work/repository/features/support/hooks.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `browser' for main:Object (NameError)
```

If I put `@browser.close` inside `at_exit`, I get:

```
/home/user/work/repository/features/support/hooks.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is there any way to open/close the browser once in a test suite and make it work with the `-d` option of cucumber?

Comment: The 'uninitialized constant Watir' error means that Watir has not been loaded. Where are you doing a "require 'watir'"?

Comment: in ```env.rb``` require 'watir-webdriver'. actually, it can't load Watir only with ```-d``` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that dry-run (-d) does not load your support/env.rb file. If you do `cucumber -h` to see the help, it says:

> -d, --dry-run  Invokes formatters without executing the steps. This also omits the loading of your support/env.rb file if it exists.

Since you require watir-webdriver in the env.rb and env.rb does not get loaded, then your hooks file will not know what Watir is.

One solution would be to add `require 'watir-webdriver'` (or `require 'watir'`) to your hooks.rb file.

An alternative solution is to move the browser creation and at_exit hooks into the env.rb file. This way, when using the dry run option, you will not see the browser open and close.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by moving require to hooks.rb. But, why when ```require``` was in ```env.rb``` and creation of new instance of the Watir-webdriver was in ```Before``` block I don't have any problem with dry run option?

Comment: When using the dry run option, nothing in the Before block will get executed (ie Ruby does not know the Watir::Browser.new command is anywhere in the code).

Comment: Re-thinking about it, it might be better to move the Watir::Browser.new and at_exit hook into the env.rb file. That way, when using the dry run option, you will not see the browser opening/closing when you are not going to use it.

Comment: When I moved Watir::Browser.new and at_exit hook to env.rb I get error ```undefined local variable or method `browser' for #<Object:0x0000000345af80> (NameError)```

Comment: Are you sure that exception is coming from the env.rb? It could be from other code that is expecting browser to exist. Hard to debug without seeing all of the code.