# Rubymine is not able to find a step definition, located inside a gem

Tags: cucumber, watir, rubymine

Rubymine returns an alert of "Undefined step reference" for the two steps of this scenario. This cucumber test is like this:

```
 @smoke
  Scenario: Update profile Smoke test.
    Given I navigate to this test webpage
      And In Test, I click the element of "test_link"
```

This 2 steps are located inside a gem, following this structure:
    gemname/lib/features/step_definitions/web_shared_steps.rb

```
And (/^I navigate to this (.*?)$/) do |web|
  web = '$' + web.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
  @browser.goto eval(web)
end

Then (/In (.*?), I click the element of "(.*?)"$/) do |page, element|
  on_page(page + 'Page').click_element(element)
end
```

And the methods are also in the gem, following this structure:
    gemname/lib/basic_methods.rb

```
module BasicMethods

  include PageObject
  include PageObject::PageFactory


  def click_element (element)
    element = element.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
    wait_until{send("#{element}?")}

    select = send("#{element}_element")
    wait_until{select.visible?}

    select.click
  end
```

So, If I execute with the command line "bundle exec cucumber", the test is able to find the step definitions in the gem, and the methods in the gem, and everything is executed correctly.

But, Rubymine is still giving an alert of "Undefined Step reference" for the two steps of the scenario, and I am unable to "command click" in those steps in order to navigate to the step definition.

QUESTION: Since the test in working, how is possible to "tell" Rubymine the folder/location where it has to search for the step definitions?

Comment: Interesting. Step definitions in a gem are unusual. Might help to spell out how the gem requires the step definitions. Did you have to do anything other than put the gem in your Gemfile for them to work?

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier. Yes, just downloading the gem, you can grab the step definitions. The problem is my IDE: Rubymine. They have some kind of "hardcoded thing" that only allows a handful of famous gems to identify step definitions contained in gems. For the rest of gems, the step definition is show as "non existent", even if it is there and everything works.

Comment: I bet this would make a good support request to JetBrains.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Rubymine so I can't verify this answer but it sounds very similar to a problem I had with Syntastic under Vim.

Try creating a file called `features/support/external.rb` containing:

```
require "lib/features/step_definitions/web_shared_steps.rb"
```

Actually it doesn't have to be called `external.rb`, it can be called anything except `env.rb`.

I'm guessing that Rubymine is calling cucumber with the `--dry-run` option to generate its warnings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18488512/195369) for details.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the gem source on your machine and then add this to your gemfile
`gem 'gem', :path => 'path/to/gem-source'`

I've had a similar problem with trying to use my own fork of a gem
When i did `gem 'my-gem', :git => 'my-repo.git'` i had the same problem as you, but by using `:path` I got rubyMine to recognise my step definitions.

I need to switch back to `:git` in production but at least i have a solution for my dev environment

Comment: this worked for me but is not optimal, I have to remember everytime before commiting to edit the Gemfile