# Rubymine Cucumber Support - Step definitions cannot be found

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rubymine

When I write down my step definitions using the pattern:

```
When /^I implement a step$/ do
# my code
end
```

Then Rubymine is able to locate the step definition and I can strg-click it to jump directly to the step definition.

When I refactor the same step definition to the following pattern (to move the implementing code to another ruby class):

```
When /^I implement a step$/, :some_implementing_method, :on => lambda { object_with_method}
```

Then Rubymine cannot find and link the step definition. In both cases, the run of the test works just fine.

I use Rubymine 6.3.3 on OS X 10.9.

What am I missing here? Or is it worth filing a bug?

Comment: Do you get step definition undefined warnings when you run cucumber at the command-line? What about when you add the `--dry-run` option?

Comment: No, the run in the command line works fine and without any warnings.

Comment: Thanks for checking. See my answer to a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28390402/195369). As I say, it's just a guess so please leave feedback if you try it.